# Attempting to report CPU clock speed continuously in batch

Tags: batch-file, cpu, wmic

I am trying to make a CPU clock speed tracker, but I need some help on the code.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
:a
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "ASCII_13=%%a"
set /p "=!ASCII_13!" <NUL
wmic cpu get CurrentClockSpeed
goto a
```

I'm interested in getting something like this:

```
CurrentClockSpeed
2401
```

not this (the code I'm trying to use outputs this):

```
CurrentClockSpeed
2401


CurrentClockSpeed
2401


CurrentClockSpeed
2401


CurrentClockSpeed
2401
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Use the `CLS` command after your label `:a`.

Answer (score 1):

`wmic` has an ugly line ending (an additional `CR`), that regularily makes trouble. In your case, it does the work for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:loop
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic cpu get LoadPercentage /value ^|find "="') do (
  set "value=%%a"
  <nul set /p "=!value:~0,-1!  !value:~-1!"
)
goto :loop
```

You should filter `wmic` output to one line (`wmic` returns some empty lines too)
(I choosed another value (LoadPercentage) to let something happen)

I assign the value (including the additional `CR`) to a variable, then write [variable minus CR] three spaces and the [last char of `value`] (which is the `CR`). 
The three spaces are neccessary to overwrite remaining characters, when the new value is shorter than the old one.

Comment: The very first iteration of the output shows as `U-Load:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "ASCII_13=%%a"
echo CurrentClockSpeed

:a
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('wmic cpu get CurrentClockSpeed') do if "%%b" neq "" set "value=%%a"
set /p "=%value%    !ASCII_13!" <NUL
goto a
```

Comment: the value is wrong, when the previous value was longer (old='1234`, new=`98` shows `9834`)

Comment: which makes our codes nearly identical `:)` (just different methods to get the `CR`)

Comment: @Stephan: Well, yeah, but your method run `find.exe` file plus _two copies_ of `cmd.exe` file in _each iteration_, so my method is more efficient! **`;)`**

Comment: I don't care about efficiency as long as `wmci` is involved... `;)`

Answer (score -1):

Simply create a `.BAT` file and paste the following code in it.
After that you can run it, hopefully this helps.

```
wmic cpu get currentclockspeed, maxclockspeed, CurrentVoltage, numberofcores, loadpercentage /every:5
```

Comment: still additional lines for each iteration. Asker wants it to overwrite previous output.