# Hide 'loading processor information' after running systeminfo

Tags: batch-file, system-information

I have another question with batch files (again concerning my processor speed tracker). I want to use systeminfo, but before the information shows, there's a obnoxious message saying

```
loading processor information...
```

than some illegible writing saying

```
loading x information...
```

where x is something like 'hyper-v'.

How can I use systeminfo without the 'loading x information' appearing?

Comment: Are you looking to view or output something specific from systeminfo?

Comment: That information is being written directly to the console.  It is not being written out using STDOUT.  You can test that real easily: `systeminfo 1>nul` It also not STDERR which you can check as: `systeminfo 2>nul`.  You can't suppress output written directly to the console.

Comment: Also, please go back to your first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187315/attempting-to-report-cpu-clock-speed-continuously-in-batch) and select an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for this batch :

```
@echo off
systeminfo > c:\infosys.txt 2>&1
start "" c:\infosys.txt
```

Comment: That is baffling to me.  Why doesn't redirecting STDERR or STDOUT by itself not work?

Comment: I do not want to save it onto a file, I want to use it in a program, like finding the memory in MB and printing it onto the console.